# pcolormesh with odd, but equal, number of x and y entries does not behave like equal, equal numbers of x and y entries

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 2d

How can I get pcolormesh to not yield extended axes when using an odd number of entries as opposed to an even number?  For instance, if I initialize a plot as follows:

```
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111,axisbg='tan')    
plot_strains = np.random.rand(16, 16)
pcm = ax2.pcolor(plot_strains, cmap='jet', edgecolors='k', linewidths=1)
fig2.colorbar(pcm)
```

I get the following plot

[image]

However, if I initialize as:

```
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111,axisbg='tan') 
plot_strains = np.random.rand(17, 17)
pcm = ax2.pcolor(plot_strains, cmap='jet', edgecolors='k', linewidths=1)
fig2.colorbar(pcm)
```

I get:
[image]

I don't want the extra "18" axes.  This behavior seems consistent across all even and odd combos.  Any pointers how to get around this?  Thanks!

Comment: [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUlfA.png) in the newest matplotlib version, which seems fine. So if you need a solution for an older version, you would probably want to state which version that is, and also why `ax.set(xlim=(0,17), ylim=(0,17))` would not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this was helpful.  The version is pinned down by another administrator so I can't change it, after checking the version it is 1.4.3.  The limits thing worked just great, thanks!

Comment: So this would work out of the box with matplotlib 2.0.2 or higher. We are now at 3.0.2. As far as I can see there is no restriction up to 2.2.3 - so maybe you can convince the admin to update to 2.2.3?